# Eclipse displaying one of the source folder (src/test) in different color compared to source folder - src/main?

Tags: maven, eclipse-photon

Please, can anyone tell me what is the difference Eclipse is depicting between (1) and (2) the attached image?

[image: eclipse-image-displaying-the-difference]

Tried googling, but couldn't find any proper source stating above :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature was introduced in Eclipse 4.8 to indicate that a source folder contains test code.

See [New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#jdt-test-sources), the section "Test sources" describes it in more detail.

I'll quote the relevant part here:

> Test source folders and dependencies are shown with a darker icon in the build path settings, the package explorer and other locations. This can be disabled in **Preferences > Java > Appearance**
>
> [image: Eclipse settings]